# Adding lists of lists, double assignment

Tags: python-3.x

Short Story: Why and in what way is the list `[2*[0]]*2` different from the list`[[0, 0], [0, 0]]`?

Long Story:

I was trying to do one of the Python Morsels exercises. Very simply: add all values of the same position in multiple lists of lists. The Example given in the question was:

```
matrix1 = [[1, -2], [-3, 4]]
matrix2 = [[2, -1], [0, -1]]
>>> add(matrix1, matrix2)
[[3, -3], [-3, 3]]
```

So I gave it a shot and wrote the following code:

```
def addmorsel(*inputslists):
    addlist = [len(inputslists[0][0])*[0]]*len(inputslists[0])
    for listoflists in inputslists:
        for i,onelist in enumerate(listoflists):
            for j,value in enumerate(onelist):
                addlist[i][j] = addlist[i][j] + value
    return addlist
```

But when I use this function on the example matrices it returns
`[[0, 0], [0, 0]]` instead of the right answer. So I printed the returned `addlist` to see what happens and apparently the line `addlist[i][j] = addlist[i][j] + value` seems to add the value to every list within a list instead of only the list it is referencing to.

Replacing the addlist creation line `addlist = [len(inputslists[0][0])*[0]]*len(inputslists[0])` by addlist = [[0,0],[0,0]] seems to do the job, but I do not understand why, because that is exactly the same as what addlist becomes by the previous line.

I thought: maybe it references the previous list or something, so I also tried `addlist = [2*[0]]*2`,so replacing the len() functions by their output, but somehow that also gives the wrong answer.

So my basic understanding of python lists is being shook here. 
Why is `[2*[0]]*2` different from `[[0, 0], [0, 0]]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly) – the sublists share the same memory address, modifying one sublist will modify the other.

Comment: Thank you for linking the question. It's answer definitely answers mine, but was not able to find it myself.